# Proof that homology groups are invariant to chosen cell structure

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have recently completed Hatcher's chapter 2 on Homology.  Although I find the arguments generally clear, I am left with some questions on details.

In particular, he shows how homology groups are formed from chains of n-cells.  The algebra and geometry are clear for the examples he presents.  However, I do not see where, if at all, we've proven that the resulting homology groups will be invariant to the cell structure chosen for a given space.

In other words, we can create any given set X from n-cells in many different ways.  Each way leads to a different set of chains.  How do we know that all such choices of cell structure for a given structure will necessarily lead to the same homology groups for that structure?

Comment: This follows once you know that singular homology is isomorphic to cellular homology on cell complexes.

Comment: This is theorem 2.35 of Hatcher.

Comment: OK, I see that.  But surely we don't have to "know about" cellular homology groups to prove that simplicial (or singular) homology groups for a given X are invariant relative to the chosen cellular structure.

Comment: Right, you don't have to know about cellular homology to prove invariance of singular. Singular homology is obviously invariant by definition. But I thought your question was about cellular homology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obviously invariant definition of homology is singular homology. It makes no reference to a cell structure or a simplicial structure. However, it is extremely unwieldy. You can't compute with it directly since the chain groups are of uncountable dimension. On the other hand, cellular homology has finitely generated chain groups (at least for finite CW complexes) so it can be used for calculations. The problem is that it is not obviously invariant under change of cell structure. Luckily however, one can prove (Theorem 2.35 of Hatcher) that they are isomorphic when both are defined. So you get the best of both worlds: topological invariance (using singular homology) and easy calculation (using cellular homology).

Comment: But how do we know singular homology groups are unique?  Surely the sigma-maps are not unique.  For example, we have three ways to map an equilateral triangle onto an equilateral triangle.

Comment: The singular chains are by definition spanned by *all* continuous maps of a simplex into your space. You get uniqueness by throwing in everything.

Comment: For your equilateral triangle example, there are uncountably many ways to map a 2-simplex into your equilateral triangle, and all of these are part of your chain group.

Comment: Ok.  I am half-way with you.  Since the singular homology groups are always defined using all the sigma-maps, there are no choices to be made, so uniqueness is assured (right?).  But, for Thrm. 2.35 each cellular homology group must be unique; otherwise the isomorphism does not make sense. So, does the uniqueness of the cellular homology groups follow from the fact that they are in the exact sequences of the singular homology groups? (As shown in the diagonals of Hatcher's diagram on p.139).

Comment: Yes, the singular homology groups are unique since there are no choices made when you defined them. The cellular homology groups are also unique up to isomorphism because they happen to calculate the same thing as singular homology, which you can prove with that diagonal diagram on p.139.

Comment: Great.  I really appreciate your help.